# Babel didn't work as expected, babel-cli just echos back the input file unchanged

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I just download Babel using npm (`npm install -g babel-cli`), but when I use babel-cli to compile code, stdout just returns an identical copy of the uncompiled code I tried to compile.

My babel version is 6.1.18 (babel-core: 6.1.21), and node version is 4.2.2.

I tested both OS X 10.9 and OS X 10.10, they have the same problem.

Bebel does not even work with the code below when I use `babel test.js`:

```
let a = '';
class b {

}
```

[image]

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli

Answer (score 2):

From [their website](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/):

> Babel 6 ships without any default transforms, so when you run Babel on
>   a file it will just print it back out to you without changing
>   anything.

run this command and install the es2015 presets first:

`npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015`

now compile with:

`babel test.js --presets es2015`

I also noticed that you *have* to do `--save-dev` when you npm install `babel-preset-es2015` and that if you just use `-g` you get the error `Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015"` so make sure to do `--save-dev` and not `-g` when installing the preset.

Answer (score 2):

As of version 6, Babel does not ship with any transformation by default. So, `babel-preset-es2015` must be installed to enable the transformations. After installation, you have to enable the preset either with a `package.json` or with the `.babelrc` file. 
A sample `package.json` file:

```js
{
  "name": "es6-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "babel": {
    "presets": ["es2015"]
  }
}
```

And if you use `.babelrc` instead:

```js
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

[This article might help with detailed instructions](http://babeljs.io/blog/2015/10/31/setting-up-babel-6/).

On a related note, if you install the preset globally with `-g` or `--global`, make sure to make a symlink in your project directory like this `npm link babel-preset-es2015`.